# Workspace Switcher

Tags: workspace, ubuntu-11.10, color-theme

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10. Since I did not like the Unity interface, I went back to using Gnome Classic with the Radiance theme. Everything looks good except for one problem: The workspace switcher does not highlight the active workspace. Is there some way to make it show which workspace is active?